# How to show tightness?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\mu_n=\delta_n$ be a point mass at $n$ (for $n=1,2,...$). Then how to show the tightness of $\{\mu_n\}$?

I tried like below.

If $\{\mu_n\}$ is tight, for all $\epsilon >0$, there are $a<b$ with $\mu_n([a,b]) \ge 1-\epsilon$ for all $n$.

So, I set $a=n-1, b=n+1$.
Then $$\mu_n([n-1,n+1])=\delta_n([n-1,n+1])=P(n-1<X<n+1)=1\ge 1-\epsilon$$
when $X\sim \delta_n$.

But I'm not sure this computation is right. Did I show the tightness properly?

Comment: You can't set $a=n-1$ or $b=n+1$. You have to find an interval $[a, b]$ that works for all $n$ simultaneously, not a different one for each $n$. Otherwise every family would be tight.

Comment: @JackM Then, is this also impossible?
If $\mu_n=Uniform[0,n]$ then $mu_n([a,b])=(b-a)/n$. So I thought that when $a=0, b=n$, $mu_n([a,b])=(n-0)/n=1 \ge 1-\epsilon$. Is this wrong to prove or disprove the tightness of $\mu_n$?

Comment: That doesn't prove tightness either, because again, tightness requires you choose an $[a, b]$ that works for every $n$. You're choosing a different $[a, b]$ for every $n$.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, $\mu_n$ is *not tight* as a family. To see this, note that every compact set is bounded, so given $K$ compact, there exists $n \in \mathbb N$ so that $n \notin K$. But then, $\mu_n(\mathbb R \backslash K) = 1$, since $n \in \mathbb R \backslash K$.

So what this means is, given $1 > \epsilon > 0$, you *cannot* find a compact $K$ such that for all $n$, $\mu_n(\mathbb R \backslash K) < \epsilon$, since we just found an $n$ for which each compact set doesn't work above.